# delete mongoDB item using model after a setTime

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am storing chat app messages in MongoDB. After X time i would like them to delete themselves.

Where in the code do i add the line from the Docs

```
{expireAfterSeconds: x }
```

My code for creating the item is

```
try {
            MessageModel.create({ 
                username: user.username,
                text: msg,
                time: moment().format('h:mm a'),
                room: user.room
            })
        } catch (error) {
        // do stuff 
}
```

and my model is set out as below

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userName: String,
        text: String,
        time: String,
        room: String
    },
    { collection: 'messages' }
)

const messageModel = mongoose.model('MessageSchema', MessageSchema)
```

Do I add the code to the model? or as a second argument to the create method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB TTL collection feature is set by using an index.

1. First, modify your time-field to store a timestamp as a valid date type. You can use `moment().toISOString()`

```js
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userName: String,
        text: String,
        time: String,
        room: String,
    },
    { collection: 'messages' }
)
```

2. Set the TTL index like so

```
db.messages.createIndex( { "time": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

For more information look at the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)